# Create a node for each column only once while importing csv into Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a csv file that looks the following way:

[image]

I want to create a database from it in `Neo4j`. Rows are nodes with labels `gene`, columns are also nodes with labels `cell`. I need to write a `CREATE` query that would create all my `gene` and `cell` - nodes and a relationship one for each combination of `gene` and `cell`. Currently I am stuck with the following code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///merged_full.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Gene {id: line.gene_ids, name: line.wikigene_name})
```

I need to somehow iterate over all columns - starting from index 3 - after creating `gene` nodes, but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 3 queries that, performed in order, should do what you want.

1. This query creates a temporary `Headers` node with a `names` property that contains the collection of headers from the CSV file. It uses `LIMIT 1` to only process the first row of the file. It also creates all the `Cell` nodes, each with it own `name` property.

   ```
   LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///merged_full.csv' AS line
   MERGE (h:Headers)
   SET h.names = line
   WITH line
   LIMIT 1
   UNWIND line[3..] AS name
   MERGE (c:Cell {name: name})
   ```
2. This query uses the APOC function [apoc.map.fromNodes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_map_functions) to generate a map named `cells`, which maps each cell name to its cell node. It also gets the `Headers` node. It then loads the non-header data from the CSV file (using `SKIP 1` to skip over the header row), and processes each row as follows. It uses `MERGE` to get/create a `Gene` node, `g`, with the desired `id` and `name`. It uses the `REDUCE` function to generate a collection of the `Cell` nodes that have a "1" column value in the current row, and the `FOREACH` clause then creates a `(g)-[:HAS]->(x)` relationship (if necessary) for every cell, `x`, in that collection.

   ```
   WITH apoc.map.fromNodes('Cell', 'name') AS cells
   MATCH (h:Headers)
   LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///merged_full.csv' AS line
   WITH h, cells, line
   SKIP 1 
   MERGE (g:Gene {id: line[1], name: line[2]})
   FOREACH(
     x IN REDUCE(s = [], i IN RANGE(3, SIZE(line)-1) |
       CASE line[i] WHEN "1" THEN s + cells[h.names[i]] ELSE s END) |
     MERGE (g)-[:HAS]->(x))
   ```
3. This query just deletes the temporary `Headers` node (if you wish):

   ```
   MATCH (h:Headers)
   DELETE h;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If the columns correspond with cell nodes, then you should know all the cell nodes you need just be looking at the CSV header.

I'd recommend writing a small query just to create each of the cell nodes you need, then create an index or unique constraint on :Cell(id) (or name, or whatever the property is that is meant to identify a :Cell).

At that point the problem becomes getting and processing each relevant column (I assume only the ones with 1 as the value). [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) may help here.

`apoc.map.sortedProperties()` can be used to take your `line` map and give you a list of key/value list pairs, which you can filter down to those where the key begins with 'V', and where the value is 1, then use what's remaining to match on the relevant :Cell node and create the relationship.

Comment: I have a trouble with it. I can iterate over rows, but not over all columns. Even if I find a way of iterating over columns, I need to do it only once, but importing csv happens row by row. So, I am pretty confused here.

Comment: Know I am thinking of just making several csv files to create a database that I need. But it should be possible with Cypher somehow to just use the one already prepared...

Comment: It is possible to do index access of the `line` mapped values, but you would have to drop `WITH HEADERS` from the LOAD CSV clause and skip the first line (since you don't want to process the headers). You would only be able to do index access, though, no mapped value access

Comment: The other issue is that the multiple MERGEs you would need to do, when adding each one of the cells corresponding with the columns, would introduce an EAGER operation in the query plan, which would prevent you from using PERIODIC COMMIT in your LOAD CSV. You don't seem to be using it now, but you won't be able to process large csv files efficiently without this.

Comment: `WITH line SKIP 1` between your LOAD and CREATE. https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/skip/

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get column name at an index?

Comment: How to iterate over a line with FOREACH? I do not know, but documentation seems to be lacking, not enough examples.

Comment: Anyway, if anyone knows how to actually write the query to achieve the results specified in the question, please, help.

Comment: I really recommend changing your approach. Iterating over columns isn't a good way to go about this. Ideally, for relationship creation, you would have already processed a CSV for creating your nodes, and you would have a separate CSV with two columns, one with the unique identifier for your :Gene node, and the other with a unique identifier for your :Cell node (both indexed). Then it's just a matter of matching to each node and merging the relationship. If not that, give the APOC approach a try.